# JsTree: - why is jsTree deleting my property?

Tags: javascript, jstree

to add nodes to my tree,  I am using javascript push:

```
var parent1 =
{
    "id": "parent1",
    "data": {extra:"some extra data"},
    "parent": "#",
    "type": "myType1",
    "text": "I am a parent",
    "state": {"opened": false}
}
nodes.push(parent1);


var child1 =
{
    "id": "Child1",
    "data": {extra:"some extra data"},
    "parent": "parent1",
    "type": "myType2",
    "text": "I am a child",
    "state": {"opened": false}
}
nodes.push(child1);

var child2 =
{
    "id": "Child2",
    "data": {extra:"some extra data"},
    "parent": "child1",
    "type": "myType3",
    "text": "I am child2",
    "state": {"opened": false}
}
nodes.push(child2);
```

As you can see, I am including extra data in the "data" property in both the parent and the child.

I am finding however, when I select a node,  the child1 var in the code below is undefined.... therefore, somehow, jsTree is deleting my data property...

```
var selectNode = function (e, item) {
    console.log('item selected %o', item);
    switch (item.node.type) {
        case "myType3":
          var child = item.node.data,
           child1NodeId = item.node.parent,
           child1Node = _.where(nodes,{id:child1NodeId}),
           child1 = child1NodeId[0].data
           break;
       }
}
```

Can anyone help?
This only seams to be happening when selecting a child of a child.

Comment: If I use a different property name other than "data" in the child object, ie: objdata, the property seams to be preserved... can someone tell me why "data" is preserved for root elements, but not children?

Comment: Strange, I remember running into the same problem, though I can't recall how I fixed it. When I have a similar (not exactly the same) child definition, it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access `item.node.data` property. Also please correct `child1` to `Child1` for parent of node `Child2`.

Your code could look like: `console.log('item selected %o', item.node.data);`

See fiddle: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/zz7n8Lre/)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The reason is how I was trying to retrieve a node.

Instead of:

```
var selectNode = function (e, item) {
console.log('item selected %o', item);
switch (item.node.type) {
    case "myType3":
      var child = item.node.data,
       child1NodeId = item.node.parent,
       child1Node = _.where(nodes,{id:child1NodeId}),
       child1 = child1NodeId[0].data
       break;
   }
```

}

I should have used the JSTree API "getNode" instead:

```
var selectNode = function (e, item) {
    console.log('item selected %o', item);
    switch (item.node.type) {
        case "myType3":
          var treeinst = $('#myTree').jstree(true),
           child = item.node.data,
           child1NodeId = item.node.parent,
           child1Node = treeInst.get_node( child1NodeId )
           child1 = child1Node.data
           break;
       }
}
```